# Add Ask Different to MS Edge Sidebar

Tags: discussion

This is just a simple "Hey!  Check out this new feature post..."

Microsoft added a sidebar and you can add in websites.  StackOverflow is already on their list, but you can add in Ask Different manually.  It provides a really nice list view of the questions.  It appears to show a  *mobile friendly* Ask Different site (see [StackExchange Responsive Design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/287258))

This is an interesting tool to keep an eye on AD while browsing elsewhere...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bonus tip - Duck Duck Go has a bang search "!ad whatever" searches ask different for whatever....

Comment: That's a great feature @bmike.  Maybe I should rename the question to something like "Ask Different/StackExchange Tips and Tricks"?

Comment: Not sure yet. Comment is fine for now - we can let it marinate a bit…

Comment: Those twp tips refer to different apps/sites and so arn't related - if we have tips they should be for separate apps. ie as a Firefox user the question is not that relevant to me

Comment: Note: there is no mobile version of any stack exchange site anymore. This is just the view you would see if you resize your window to be that narrow.

Comment: Good to know @CaveJohnson.  I guess I should note that it provides a “mobile friendly” site due to responsive web design?

Comment: @Allan Yea that sounds about right.